# Flutter report the function 'run' isn't defined

Tags: flutter

I can run my project,but in dart Analysis there is wrong :"The function "run" isn't defined." in integration_test

1. I don't know the feature of the integration_test
2. how I remove the wrong

here is code in integration_test:

'''void main() => run(_testMain)'''

Comment: remove that folder and run the code

Comment: thank you ,it helps me, but I also want to kown the feature of the floder

Comment: That is for Unit tests and widget tests. If you want to test only single method or widget functionality then you can do it. More details https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction